# How can I reference an enum of another class in ObjectDataProvider?

Tags: wpf

I want to bind an enum to the `ComboBox`.
Here is the class `BarcodeModel.cs` which contains the enum:
[image]

And here is the enum in the class:

```
public enum BarcodeType
        { AZTEC, CODABAR, CODE128, CODE93, CODE39, DATA_MATRIX, EAN13, EAN8, ITF, MAXICODE, PDF417, QRCODE, RSS14, RSSEXPANDED, UPCA, UPCE, UPC_EAN_EXTENSION }
```

Well, in another directory of the same project I use an `ObjectDataProvider` to bind it:

```
<Page x:Class="KongGamLung.ToolProperty.BarCodeProperty"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KongGamLung.ToolProperty"
      xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:KongGamLung.Models"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="BarCodeProperty">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" MethodName="GetValues"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="Model:BarcodeModel.BarcodeType"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Page.Resources>
<ComboBox x:Name="BarcodeTypeCB" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}"></ComboBox>
</Page>
```

After it ran, Visual Studio threw a XamlParseException error which can not find “`{clr-namespace:KongGamLung.Models;assembly=KongGamLung, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}BarcodeModel.BarcodeType`”

How can I reference the enum correctly? Would you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference a nested type in xaml, instead of '.', use '+'.

```
<x:Type TypeName="Model:BarcodeModel+BarcodeType"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! Whereas, I feel strange c# use + but not . in this place. Aha.

Comment: @102425074 Actually, the offical type name of a nested type is using '+'. You can check `Type.FullName` of a nested type.